# Microsoft SignalR demo error

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm doing the Microsoft SignalR Self Hosting example on

[SignalR Demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

I copied and pasted the code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is straight from the page.  It errors on

```
using (WebApp.Start(url))

// also tried
// WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080");
```

with the error "System.NullreferenceException Object not set to instance of an object".  After reading some articles I tried opening the port in Windows Firewall, entering the IP instead of localhost, changing the port, and downgrading the SignalR version since the article is from 2014.  Nothing worked.  I'm using

Windows 10 pro
Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost 2.2.3
Microsoft.Owin.Cors 4.0.0

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what was the full text of the exception? I suspect some configuration section is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I did wrong.  I created the console app as a .net framework "core" instead of the full .net 4.6.  Everything worked after that.